# Epson XP202 will not install

Tags: drivers, software-center, printing

I am using 14.04 which has been great until today trying to print using Epson XP202. Previously the printer worked after installing drivers no problem on older versions of Ubuntu/Lubuntu.

Now I have tried simply adding the printer and letting Ubuntu find and install driver - this asks for password then freezes.

I have tried via software centre it either freezes and crashes or it cues me behind an update which never finishes.

I have tried from Epson site but it just goes into download folder or prompts software centre to open and then freezes again.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use gdebi instead of softwarecenter and download and install the drivers from EPSON *one by one* in order, start at the top and work your way down using the list below.

First, install gdebi:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gdebi
```

Then, right click on the driver deb in your download folder and select "Open With", then choose gdebi from the list. Select to install the package and you will then be asked for a password. If there ate any dependency issues an error message will fully explain the details.

I believe the list below is the correct order of packages to install sequentially without dependency issues.

**If you are using a 64 bit ubuntu, just download the "amd64" packages instead of "i386".** i386 packages are just shown here as an example but the order remains the same.

- epson-inkjet-printer-201203w_1.0.0-1lsb3.2_**i386.deb**
  (full-feature)
- epson-inkjet-printer-escpr_1.4.0-1lsb3.2_**i386.deb**
  (generic-driver)
- iscan-data_1.28.0-2_all.**deb** (core & data)
- iscan_2.29.3-1~usb0.1.ltdl7_**i386.deb** (core & data)
- iscan-network-nt_1.1.1-1_**i386.deb** (network plugin)

---

To fix the error run these commands and please post any more errors.

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get -f install
```

---

Try these commands first. You might have a problem if you stopped the installation process during an upgrade. This is what I used in the past to fix this problem. What this does is it re-builds your package list.

```
sudo apt-get clean 
cd /var/lib/apt 
sudo mv lists lists.old 
sudo mkdir -p lists/partial 
sudo apt-get clean 
sudo apt-get update
```

Sometimes, to deal with broken packages, install synaptic if it's not already installed:

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

To start synaptic:

```
sudo synaptic
```

Then, click on "Edit", select "fix broken packages" and then click "apply". Please post any more errors.

Comment: Ok thanks I just did the update and install gdebi, i got this:                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 libssl1.0.0:i386
 libpam-systemd:i386
 man-db
 openssl
 debhelper
 alien
 flashplugin-installer
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: @SilatScgRobinson I've updated the answer.

Comment: Errors were encountered while processing:
 libssl1.0.0:i386
 libpam-systemd:i386
 man-db
 openssl
 debhelper
 alien
 flashplugin-installer
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: I clicked 'fix broken packages' it says successfully fixed dependency problems. It would not allow me to apply it was still greyed out. Many thanks.

Comment: @SilatScgRobinson Yeah, I realized you've probably got a problem because you stopped one of the installations earlier and need to rebuild your package list. (read update ) But if it's fixed and everything installs don't worry about it.

Comment: Just tried it again and the update worked but the install says nothing needs to be installed?                                                               E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: @SilatScgRobinson no packages are listed?